# polly.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/speech returns 200 on ubuntu 18 but forbidden 403 on ubuntu 16 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-polly

AWS polly polly.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/speech does not work on ubuntu 16 server and returns 403 forbidden but it works on 18 ubuntu and returns 200 OK.
I am facing this issue and wired to understand the reason behind it.

What can be reason behind it ? And how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you checked from which IP your different servers are located? Would most likely be due to a whitelisting/blacklisting of these IPs

Comment: Looks like an authorization/authentication issue, check your security groups or IAM permissions.  Definitely not an issue with any Linux distribution or version.

Comment: I have followed AWS signature 4 process for authentication and it is smoothly working on Ubuntu 18 server. I have provided full access policy for IAM and Polly as well at IAM group level.

Comment: Both servers are hosted on same local network and public ip is same.

Answer (score 0):

Dear guys,
Finally I got the actual reason behind it.  I checked today and found it was due to the next date set 15 MAY, 15:10:00" at this Ubuntu 16 server. When I changed to today's date time and tested it. The api was fired with 200,OK.

Actually current date time is used in calculating AWS Signature 4 Code so it could not be matched with AWS server side in a particular region.

Below are the logs::

root@abc:/usr/local/vvv/Demo_Project# date
Sat May 15 15:07:09 IST 2021
root@abc:/usr/local/vvv/Demo_Project# java -jar AWSTTS.jar
AWS jsonString Format :: 2021-05-15 15:07:17.482
2021-05-15 15:07:18.981
AWS ResponseCode & ResponseMessage :: 403 Forbidden
3.  2021-05-15 15:07:19.229
root@abc:/usr/local/vvv/Demo_Project# date -s "14 MAY 2021 15:07:00"
Fri May 14 15:07:00 IST 2021
root@abc:/usr/local/vvv/Demo_Project# java -jar AWSTTS.jar
AWS jsonString Format :: 2021-05-14 15:07:04.650
2021-05-14 15:07:04.653
AWS ResponseCode & ResponseMessage :: 200 OK
3.  2021-05-14 15:07:06.295